# How to prove $\sin^2{7\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}=\sin{11\theta}\sin{3\theta}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I've tried starting from both sides, the furthest I've gone is by starting from the right hand side:
$$\begin{align*}
\sin{11\theta}\sin{3\theta}&=\sin{(7\theta+4\theta)}\sin{(7\theta-4\theta)} \\
\\
&=(\sin{7\theta}\cos{4\theta}+\sin{4\theta}\cos{7\theta})(\sin{7\theta}\cos{4\theta}-\sin{4\theta}\cos{7\theta}) \\
\\
&=\sin^2{7\theta}\cos^2{4\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}\cos^2{7\theta}
\end{align*}$$

Have I done the identity wrong, or should I be using a different approach?

Comment: In the equality you want to prove, expand each side using Euler's formula $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and you get instantaneously the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$\begin{align*}
> \sin{11\theta}\sin{3\theta}&=\sin{(7\theta+4\theta)}\sin{(7\theta-4\theta)} \\
> \\
> &=(\sin{7\theta}\cos{4\theta}+\sin{4\theta}\cos{7\theta})(\sin{7\theta}\cos{4\theta}-\sin{4\theta}\cos{7\theta}) \\
> \\
> &=\sin^2{7\theta}\cos^2{4\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}\cos^2{7\theta}
> \end{align*}$$

You are almost there, keep going,

$$\begin{align}\sin^2{7\theta}\cos^2{4\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}\cos^2{7\theta}&=\sin^2{7\theta}(1-\sin^2{4\theta})-\sin^2{4\theta}(1-\sin^2{7\theta})\\
\\
&=\sin^2{7\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^2{7\theta}-\sin^2{4\theta}=(\sin7\theta - \sin4\theta)\times (\sin7\theta + \sin4\theta)$

$2 \sin(\frac{7\theta - 4\theta}{2}) \cos(\frac{7\theta + 4\theta}{2}) \times 2 \sin(\frac{7\theta + 4\theta}{2}) \cos(\frac{7\theta - 4\theta}{2})=$

$= 2 \sin(\frac{3\theta}{2}) \cos(\frac{11\theta}{2}) \times 2 \sin(\frac{11\theta}{2}) \cos(\frac{3\theta}{2})=$

$=2 \sin(\frac{3\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{3\theta}{2})\times
2 \sin(\frac{11\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{11\theta}{2})=$

$=\sin3\theta \sin11\theta$